# When to use Update vs Invalidate Cache Protocols

Tags: caching, parallel-processing, consistency

In what scenarios would it be better to use an update protocol vs an invalidate protocol? Also when would it be better to use an invalidate vs update?

I'm not able to think of any scenarios in which either would be used. If you're going to invalidate a cache line why not just update it at the same time?

Comment: Does my answer help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cache invalidation could be on multiple bases. It could be based on time, sliding window, based on other items within the cache or it could be from any data source.

Updating a cache is relatively a more expensive process. Considering what your data source is, it might cost you precious resources for something that would not be needed for some time.

So the question would be as why to invalidate items and why / when should you update them ?

Well, it completely depends on what is your use case. Do you want your items to automatically expire or have a dependency on any item.

When and why do you want to update them is also dependent on your use case. Would you need that item if it has not been accessed for the last 15 minutes or hours ? Why not update it only when it has been invalidated or expired.

In caches there is another concept of Read-Through. It calls for an update of item from your data source if it does not exist in the cache.